# chosen select delay on page load while applying $(".chzn-select").chosen();

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

Hi i am using `Chosen` a jQuery plugin for dropdowns. All is working fine but the problem is that on page load first it displays dropdowns simple i.e without styling of Chosen pluging then after 3-4 seconds it applies style on drop downs.
here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"                               OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProducts_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="chzn-select">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

[on page load]

Comment: Osama 3-4 seconds are like years in modern browsers and PCs you are doing something wrong, no html must load this much

Comment: May be your document taking time to get itself ready , therefore you are getting a 3-4 second delay.

Comment: but this issue is also present here https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: try this: `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"                               OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProducts_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="chzn-select">
    </asp:DropDownList><script>$(".chzn-select").chosen();</script>`

Comment: if you go there and notice the drop down which is using chosen style displays after a break when you refresh page but the simple drop down without chzn-select appears from start.

Comment: Yeh @Osama, while my wait is not 3-4 seconds its definitely noticable and off-putting thing about chosen. and good point re even the demo does the delay.